# How to get all/global match results for a string?

Tags: vimscript

With vim script I can do `let found = matchstr("abbaba", 'a')` and get back `"a"` as a result. How would I matchstr to get back a list of all matches for the string? `found == ["a", "a", "a"]` as in `g/a/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An alternative to repeatedly calling `match(` is to use `substitute(` with a `\=` expression:

```
function MatchStrAll(str, pat)
    let l:res = []
    call substitute(a:str, a:pat, '\=add(l:res, submatch(0))', 'g')
    return l:res
endfunction
```

Comment: Are there special regex rules for `substitute`? Because when I match a document with `\v(\<)@<=[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{-}(\:|\>|\,)@=` I get all matches. If I `let lst = []` then `%s/\v(\<)@<=[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{-}(\:|\>|\,)@=/\=add(lst, submatch(0))/gn` It works also fine. I assume substitute does the same thing? I tried adding an n flag but no results `call substitute(a:str, a:pat, '\=add(l:res, submatch(0))', 'gn')`

Comment: what is a:str and a:pat in your case?  there are a few differences but I don't think apply to you.  also as far as I know there is no 'n' flag to `substitute(`  (only to `:substitute`, function vs command)

Comment: str is `join(getline(1, '$'), "\n")` and pat is `\v(\<)@<=[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{-}(\:|\>|\,)@=`

Comment: It's probably because you're using double quotes in the pattern.  switch to single quotes `'(\<)@<=[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{-}(\:|\>|\,)@='`.  see `:help expr-quote`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `{count}` parameter for `matchstr()` to increment your way through the string and give you all the matches.

Here is an example `MatchStrAll()` function doing just that:

```
function! MatchStrAll(expr, pat, ...)
  let start = a:0 ? a:1 : 0
  let lst = []
  let cnt = 1
  let found = match(a:expr, a:pat, start, cnt)
  while found != -1
    call add(lst, matchstr(a:expr, a:pat, start, cnt))
    let cnt += 1
    let found = match(a:expr, a:pat, start, cnt)
  endwhile
  return lst
endfunction
```

Usage:

```
echo MatchStrAll("abbaba", 'a')
" yields: ['a', 'a', 'a']
```

For more help see:

```
:h match()
:h matchstr()
```

#### Something different

> I meant trying to do something like this `MatchStrAll(join(getline(1, '$'), "\n"), pattern)` and getting back a list of all matches

This would be far easier with a substitution and a sub-replace-expression.

```
:let lst = []
:%s/pattern/\=add(lst, submatch(0))/gn
```

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h sub-replace-expression
:h submatch()
:h List
```

Comment: I saw the `{count}` option in `:help` but it never explains what it does or how to use it. Can you give me a quick rundown, I'm trying to grok your code right now. I want to also use `matchstr` to return all instances of a match in a single string with line breaks.

Comment: Use `join()` to join the list together. e.g. `:echo join(MatchStrAll("abbaba", 'a'), "\n")`

Comment: I meant trying to do something like this MatchStrAll(join(getline(1, '$'), "\n"), pattern) and getting back a list of all matches.

Comment: "When {count} is given use the {count}'th match."